# Running ANOVAs across columns within a dataframe

Tags: r, purrr, anova

I have the following data frame:

```
df<- structure(list(Group.1 = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L), BLC = c(10.9890294366989, 7.31930466605672, 
13.6185172644819, 2.7266530334015, 3.53565114908662, 7.20597804412166, 
2.78164116828929, 7.59371098030222, 14.7343839844163, 2.9806259314456, 
5.07619453154234, 6.88503820786366, 12.2882487654356, 1.40646976090014, 
19.307342679726, 15.0249870253821, 4.34581364475618, 5.03491248395278, 
7.94957003082448, 6.84343434343434, 11.2622383086214, 11.1839711729262, 
4.7669094503789, 3.09762397594833, 8.10311438552811, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0), BLG = c(53.2196490874651, 23.9543988057977, 46.2826752583327, 
34.9096813849679, 27.0376341826749, 49.2472186166963, 93.0631982759938, 
46.1366527251764, 57.6460095990237, 36.5835422650789, 56.2627854701592, 
30.1133129448127, 22.2997436361558, 28.9793549481134, 37.6201098690056, 
59.8627031558285, 34.7171109184231, 48.9414623325316, 31.5061417556072, 
21.2521546878513, 70.8263794749462, 24.930952093699, 39.307162693975, 
28.9144148451338, 42.9157121339545, 3.94736842105263, 3.94736842105263, 
3.94736842105263, 3.94736842105263, 3.94736842105263), LMB = c(75.2718187185061, 
42.707035200077, 31.37371428004, 24.9294274297168, 21.619318105277, 
19.8056309622509, 62.5665072062847, 30.2395840472535, 36.2246969501391, 
16.053874321678, 73.325176836826, 32.1599744373439, 33.8619234899393, 
39.1278597999347, 29.242123346214, 50.3372863653836, 23.3365756853847, 
61.7018803213189, 18.2047745554517, 40.1231815267265, 36.2849916132823, 
35.4393881210482, 41.6277079218274, 27.5840809362335, 14.5766262544513, 
19.7368421052632, 19.7368421052632, 19.7368421052632, 19.7368421052632, 
19.7368421052632), RSF = c(7.7061355134565, 6.57544180671257, 
21.6485001821173, 14.3568910671585, 3.53565114908662, 2.89876366994815, 
10.1680661480383, 17.3890884998598, 6.45810108311722, 2.95766439639045, 
13.7591229373968, 21.1086837581149, 3.65965233302836, 26.151881306845, 
9.17122695497959, 16.6545469585419, 8.26685329264933, 9.3745854643381, 
1.4903129657228, 23.6018678125026, 7.04954072403232, 11.1546894959865, 
20.5987856222152, 8.10190710702138, 4.41849566570698, 3.94736842105263, 
3.94736842105263, 3.94736842105263, 3.94736842105263, 3.94736842105263
), GSF = c(0, 0, 0, 2.51341949455157, 8.34660636193077, 3.23362974939369, 
2.85602204934611, 3.23362974939369, 3.63636363636364, 3.9344262295082, 
0, 0, 3.9344262295082, 0, 1.46520146520147, 0, 0, 0, 3.9344262295082, 
3.63636363636364, 1.46342316809685, 0.879120879120879, 0, 0, 
2.36065573770492, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), CCF = c(0, 0, 0, 3.14465408805032, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.24223602484472, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.24223602484472, 
0, 1.88679245283019, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), design = c("random", 
"random", "random", "random", "random", "random", "random", "random", 
"random", "random", "strat", "strat", "strat", "strat", "strat", 
"strat", "strat", "strat", "strat", "strat", "hybrid", "hybrid", 
"hybrid", "hybrid", "hybrid", "hybrid", "hybrid", "hybrid", "hybrid", 
"hybrid")), row.names = c(NA, -30L), class = "data.frame")
```

I need to run an ANOVA for each column grouped by the design variable. So for example, I'm looking to do an ANOVA for species BLG, testing for a difference in the values between each design. I can do that for a single species via filtering, but I need to do the same thing for every other column as well, and many more data frames of similar format. Then doing the same thing but for a post-hoc test where there are differences found between designs for each species.

I'm guessing there is a way to do this with something like `map()` or `lapply()`. My original thought was to make a model for each column such as `model<- lm(BLG ~ design, data=df)`, and use this format in the `map` function to do this for each other column, then proceed with a similar method for the ANOVA test, but I am getting stuck (basically at the very beginning).

This is where I am currently at:

```
test<- df %>% 
  names() %>% 
  paste('design ~', .) %>% 
  map(~lm(as.formula(.x), data=df))
```

Resulting in the following error:

```
Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 
  NA/NaN/Inf in 'y'
In addition: Warning message:
In storage.mode(v) <- "double" : NAs introduced by coercion
```

My guess is that the issue is something similar to example 2 from this [link](https://statisticsglobe.com/r-error-in-lm-fit-na-nan-inf#example-2-wrong-target-variable-in-linear-regression-model), but I'm not sure what would go there if not the "design" column.

Any help or resources anyone has in mind that may be useful would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `design` is `character` class.  Should the formula be reversed? Based on the `?lm` documentation

> Models for lm are specified symbolically. A typical model has the form response ~ terms where **response is the (numeric) response vector** and terms is a series of terms which specifies a linear predictor for response

```
purrr::map(names(df)[2:7], ~ lm(reformulate('design', response = .x), data = df))
```

-output

```
[[1]]

Call:
lm(formula = reformulate("design", response = .x), data = df)

Coefficients:
 (Intercept)  designrandom   designstrat  
       3.841         3.507         4.575  


[[2]]

Call:
lm(formula = reformulate("design", response = .x), data = df)

Coefficients:
 (Intercept)  designrandom   designstrat  
       22.66         24.14         14.49  


[[3]]

Call:
lm(formula = reformulate("design", response = .x), data = df)

Coefficients:
 (Intercept)  designrandom   designstrat  
       25.42         10.66         14.72  


[[4]]

Call:
lm(formula = reformulate("design", response = .x), data = df)

Coefficients:
 (Intercept)  designrandom   designstrat  
       7.106         2.263         6.218  


[[5]]

Call:
lm(formula = reformulate("design", response = .x), data = df)

Coefficients:
 (Intercept)  designrandom   designstrat  
      0.4703        2.3051        0.8267  


[[6]]

Call:
lm(formula = reformulate("design", response = .x), data = df)

Coefficients:
 (Intercept)  designrandom   designstrat  
     0.18868       0.12579       0.05977
```